# Как отследить ререндер страницы чистым js?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-events, render

Вопрос скорее всего задан не корректно, но по-другому не могу сформировать мысль.

Суть в чём, есть конструктор сайтов написанный, по моим предположениям на vue, который, помимо предустановленных элементов, позволяет добавить элементы со свой html кодом. Я добавил скрип, который навешивает слушателей(клик, …). Когда происходит начальная загрузка все работает хорошо, ну по крайней мере ожидаемо. Но, когда начинаешь переходить по страницам, все слушатели слетают, ведь фактически нет перезагрузки страницы и слушатели заново не навешиваются.

Какое решение придумал я: рекурсивный таймер. Через каждых 3 секунды я заново навешиваю слушателей событий.

```
let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link');
const descriptionSections = document.querySelectorAll('.description__body');
if (menus) {

const action = function (e) {
  const itemName = e.target.dataset.id;
  menus.forEach(menuItem => {
    menuItem.dataset.id === itemName
      ? menuItem.classList.add('active')
      : menuItem.classList.remove('active');
  });
  const item = document.querySelector(`#${itemName}`);
  if (itemName && item) {
    descriptionSections.forEach(section => {
      section.id === itemName
        ? section.removeAttribute('hidden')
        : section.setAttribute('hidden', '');
    });
  }
};
menus.forEach(menu => menu.addEventListener('click', action));
}
timerId = setTimeout(tick, 3000); 
}, 3000);
```

Но, что-то подсказывает мне что так делать не очень хорошо.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть другие способы реализации моего замысла. Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: доступа к  исходному коду на vue я так понимаю нету?

Comment: нет, это таплинк, на котором ты просто добавляешь нужные тебе блоки

Comment: Повесьте слушатель на  `popstate`, либо любое другое изменение истории или адресной строки, и в обработчике заново вызывайте свой скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

доступа к  исходному коду на vue я так понимаю нету?   если нету и нужно обрабатывать  события то можно использовать несколько вариантов -

1. навесить  слушатель на body и  ловить  ev.target.
   например

```js
const body = document.body.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    const isMenu = ev.target.matches('menu'); // проверяем тот ли это элемент
    if (isMenu) {
        // своой код обработки
        console.log('i sMenu');
    } else {
        console.log('is not menu');
    }
});
```

```css
#body{
width:100%;
height:100vh}

menu{height:10vh; background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div id = "body">
<div><menu></menu></div>
</div>
```

Вариант два - схожий -  через  MutationObserver;

https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто отслеживать переход по ссылкам/кнопкам с помощью:

```
//вызывается при клике на ссылку
function goToNextPage() {
    //...тут перевешиваем обработчики
}
```